# cd doesn't work in script with quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I came across a strange problem. If I enter in terminal `cd "folder"` (with quotes around folder name), it works.

But if I use the code bellow in my bash script, it gives me an error saying that the folder doesn't exist.

```
path="\"folder\""
echo $path   ---> outputs "folder", with quotes
cd $path
```

I am located in the same folder when I write `cd "folder"` in terminal and when I run the script bellow.

What is the problem?

**EDIT:** To make myself clear. I need to use quotes around folder name because some of the folders contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The shell will expand the parameters once. With `cd "folder"` the quotes are removed before the `cd` is executed. Fine.
With `cd $path` the shell will translate `$path` in a string with quotes. `cd` tries to find the directory with quotes in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes like below:-

```
 cd "$path"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to go to `'"folder"'` not to `'folder'` than mean you are trying to access to `"folder"` not to `folder`. I guess you want to access `folder`.

Quote are to define a string, in your case, you do not need it in the string content.
When you write `cd "folder"` you define a string witch contain `folder`

You must rework your data's source to remove unwanted quote.

Like @Abhijit Pritam answered, if you have space or character that could be interpreted by the shell, you can surround your variable by doubles quotes: `cd "$path"`. As specified in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’.
>
> [...]The characters ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes

So the code, with removed double quotes from the data's source:

```
path="folder with space"
echo -n $path   ---> outputs folder with space
cd "$path"
```

I suggest you to do not have space in folder's name, it prevents space issues.

Comment: What if my folder name contains spaces? Then I need to put quotes around the path.

Comment: like @Abhijit Pritam answered, you can put your variable inside quotes. I will edit

Comment: you overwrote the PATH variable, so your shell now cannot find programs. This is why we say not to use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks, I edited